# Unable to display image, stored on aws s3, through HTML page

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've uploaded a file to s3, bucketname = newtestshivcloudtech.
Made bucket public, made the file (shiva.jpg) public
Added below bucket policy to the bucket for anonymous access.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::newtestshivcloudtech/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Launched an EC2 instance, installed httpd, created index.html file as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

   <h2>Picture of Shiva</h2>
   <img src=”https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/newtestshivcloudtech/shiva.jpg” 
   />

  </body>
</html>
```

If I browse to the ec2 dns "http://ec2-13-59-76-186.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/"

Page loads up but the image doesn't load. Shows the broken image icon.

Inspect using the browser shows the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/787VG.png)

Any clue or ideas?

Comment: You appear to have deleted this bucket after posting the question.

Comment: From the error it seems, that the current url of the site is appended to the image url from server. Will you be able to viewsource in browser (Chrome) and observer whether the appended wrong url comes from the server?

Comment: Thanks for the attempts folks. Yes, I deleted the links and aws resources. I will try and do this again today. the source looked intact and had the right ink. I even tried to use the bucket name first like mentioned by some folks during my research, but the result remained pretty similar. The link was directly taken from the object description in aws s3.